# Is it possible to send the value of the Tab Key in Selenium?

Tags: selenium

I ran into a scenario recently where a user copied the value of a tab key plus some characters from a word document and pasted it into a field in the application.

The value would look like this: `"TEST  "`

The regex for the input field allows alpha-numeric and underscores and trims out spaces. But for some reason it allows the tab and does not see it as a space and therefore did not trim it out.

It caused issues for the application and we have since fixed the problem, but I am trying to find a way to add this as a part of the Selenium Automation scripts.

So is there any way for Selenium to send the value of a tab, and not treat the send keys for the Tab as someone pressing the Tab button?

Answer (score 0):

```
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium")
mess_age = "Hey how are you     "
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='q']").send_keys(mess_age)
```

http://youtu.be/thWOLJYrF2s?hd=1 (this is how it performs)

Comment: In both situations the form treats it as if you are clicking the tab key not actually inserting the value of tab

Comment: can I see what you're looking to fill out?